# Php foreach data insert

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Hi i have an app on Joomla + php + Mysql. The array passed into function where it will be insert into mysql database. Following are my code.

```
public function setItems($params,$type)
{
$search_id = 1;
$query = $db->getQuery( true );
$columns = array('query_type','query_name','search_id');
foreach($params['banks'] as $key=>$value){
            $values = array($db->quote('bank'), $db->quote($value), $db->quote($search_id));
            $query->insert($db->quoteName('#__bank_parameters'))
              ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
              ->values(implode(',',$values));
             $db->setQuery($query);
             $db->query();

        }

}
```

The output of params as follow:

```
Array
(
    [0] => bank1
    [1] => bank2
)
```

The issues now, i am only getting one data insertion, not 2 as how the params above has. What might be missing here? Thanks

Comment: don't know this query builder but might it be possible that you need to call `$query = $db->getQuery( true );` again inside the loop before the second go round?

Comment: Where is `$db` defined?

Comment: A lot of times actually you want to do $query->clear();

Answer (score 2):

`Insert` and `Columns` should be used once, `Values` multiple times:

```
// Create the base insert statement.
$query
   ->clear()
   ->insert(    $db->qn('#__bank_parameters'))
   ->columns(   array('query_type', 'query_name', 'search_id'))
;

foreach ($params['banks'] as $key => $value)
{
    $query->values(implode(', ', $db->q(array('bank', $value, $search_id))))
}

// Set the query and execute the insert.
$db->setQuery($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an solution for above problems.

```
foreach($params['banks'] as $key=>$value){
            $query = $db->getQuery( true );
            $columns = array('query_type','query_name','search_id');
            $values = array($db->quote('bank'), $db->quote($value), $db->quote($search_id));
            $query->insert($db->quoteName('#__bank_parameters'))
              ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
              ->values(implode(',',$values));
             $db->setQuery($query);
             $db->query();

        }
```

Thanks to  `Orangepill`

Answer (score 0):

Create object of db  $db = JFactory::getDbo();

```
  public function setItems($params,$type)
        {
        $search_id = 1;
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery( true );
        $columns = array('query_type','query_name','search_id');
        foreach($params['banks'] as $key=>$value){
                    $values = array($db->quote('bank'), $db->quote($value), $db->quote($search_id));
                    $query->insert($db->quoteName('#__bank_parameters'))
                      ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
                      ->values(implode(',',$values));
                     $db->setQuery($query);
                     $db->query();

                }

    }
```